# JPQL ElementCollection: getting all users which have at least one role of a list

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

A user may play many roles. I want to fetch all users which have at least one role out of a parameter list.

The data definition looks as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id",
            nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "LoginName",
            length = 30,
            unique = true,
            nullable = false)
    private String loginName;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "Role",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Id"),
                     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"Id", "Role"}))
    @Column(name = "Role")
    private Set<RoleType> roles = new HashSet<RoleType>();
}


public enum RoleType {
    GUEST,
    ACCOUNTING,
    ADMIN,
    OPERATOR;
}
```

Now I want all users which have at least one role out of a parameter list. The list may be dynamically. I tried the following code:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles AS r WHERE r IN :filteredRoles";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
List<RoleType> filteredRoles = new ArrayList<RoleType>();
filteredRoles.add(RoleType.ADMIN);
filteredRoles.add(RoleType.ACCOUNTING);
query.setParameter("filteredRoles", filteredRoles);
List<User> result = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
```

and receive the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6078] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The class of the argument for the object comparison is incorrect. 
Expression: [null] 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectCollectionMapping[roles]] 
Argument: [[ADMIN, ACCOUNTING]]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT DISTINCT t0.Id FROM User t0, Role t1 WHERE ((t1.Role IN ?) AND (t1.Id = t0.Id))")
```

I tried several variations of the JPQL but didn't succeed.
I hope to receive helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the 2.4 release, this seems like something that was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, it will be best soluction. I hope it will be helpful for you;

```
public enum Role {
    AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD;
}

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "Role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Id"),
                     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "Id", "Role" }))
    @Column(name = "Role")
    private List<Role> roleList;

    public Student() {
    }

    //gettter and setter
}

/**
    Assume :
    ==================          ================
    Student Table               Role Table
    ==================          ================
    R001    Student 1           R001    AAA
    R002    Student 2           R002    BBB
    R003    Student 3           R002    CCC
    R004    Student 4           R004    DDD
                                R001    BBB
                                R002    CCC

*/
public class TestCase {
    public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
        Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>();
        for (T x : setA)
          if (setB.contains(x))
            tmp.add(x);
        return tmp;
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Set<Role> paramRoles = new HashSet<Role>();
        paramRoles.add(Role.BBB);
        paramRoles.add(Role.CCC);

        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s");
        List<Student> studentList = q.getResultList();
        for (Student s : studentList) {
            Set<Role> result = TestCase.intersection(paramRoles, new HashSet<Role>(s.getRoleList()));
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(s.getName());
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}

/** Output :

Student 1
Student 2

*/
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? I don't see how renaming RoleType to Role and using a List instead of a Set might help.

Comment: Yes, thz for your comment. It will be better to use `Set`.

Comment: The problem is in the JPQL where I receive the exception:

Comment: You see the JPQL above in the code snippet: SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles AS r WHERE r IN :filteredRoles. When I call getResultList(), I receive the exception that you may see above after the code snippet.

Comment: I see, did u try as my example? is it work or not for you? Would you like to solve using JPQL, not programmatically?

Comment: I think that solution is only a workaround if I don't get the database doing what I expect from it. Filtering is a database job because databases are optimized in doing that.